# Can you programmatically determine the sender of a value down a go channel from the receiver?

Tags: go, channel

Lets say I have a buffered channel, with different functions {A,B,C and D} sending values into the channel at different times. Now if I read a notification from the channel is there any way to determine which sender it came from? Logically I would assume no but I don't have enough understanding of channel internals to know what is possible yet?

If this channel was perhaps a unbuffered channel could you find the corresponding sender as if you are receiving a value you cant move on until there is one sender sending at that exact time.

Is the only way to be sure to load up delve and take a look at all the goroutines that are operating at the time or put logging statements before every send to the channel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to tell who sent the value you receive from a channel.

But it's easy to implement that if you need it. Just wrap the value and a sender ID in a struct, and modify senders to send a struct value on the channel, filled the sender ID.

Comment: As I expected, makes sense. Thanks for that :)